# Enviar coordenadas en javascript y ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, mvc

tengo una duda, tengo una función en javascript, pero al parecer no recibe bien las coordenadas, al poner el mouse sobre el link que llama la función, se nota que si van las coordenadas. Adjunto el código de la función y el error generado

```js
function VerRuta(origen, destino){

           var ori = { lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0 };
           var dest = { lat: 0.0, lng: 0.0 };
           ///Para crear una ruta
           ////alert("origen: " + origen.lat + " " + origen.lng + " Destino: " + destino.lat + " " + destino.lng);
           var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-geolocation1'), {
               center: { lat: -0.248207, lng: -78.480393 },
               zoom: 8
           });
           var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
               map: map
           });

           //// Asignar el destinatario y el origen, ademas del modo de viaje.
           alert(ori.lat);
           var request = {
               destination: destino,
               origin: origen,
               travelMode: 'DRIVING'
           };
           //// Pasamos las direcciones al servicio de direcciones.
           var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
           directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {

               if (status == 'OK') {
                   // Mostramos la ruta en el mapa.
                   directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);

               } else {
                   alert(status);
               }
           });
       }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y este es el error que arroja:

> "InvalidValueError: in property origin: not a string; and not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: not an Object; and not an Object"

Al parecer no detecta una latitud y longitud válida.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el codigo noto que usas

```
alert(ori.lat);
```

pero en ningun momento asignas esa variable al `DirectionsService`, en cambio asignas el parametro `origen`, el cual no evaluas su contenido, por lo tanto recomendaria uses

```
alert(origen.lat);
```

para evaluar si defines las coordenadas que usara google maps

Ademas si analizas la documentacion

[Directions Service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions?hl=es)

veras que el origen y destino requieren un texto, no veo que usen coordenadas de latitud/longuitud, podrias intentar definir de forma fija el json que asignas al `directionsService.route()` para validar que funcione correctamente

```
{
  origin: "Chicago, IL",
  destination: "Los Angeles, CA",
  travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
}
```

Si revisas el ejemplo

[Place Autocomplete and Directions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions?hl=es)

podras analizar como resuelve el `place` para definir el origen y destino